# Using byobu and git post-receive hook

Tags: git, git-post-receive, byobu

As part of my post-receive hook I checkout the HEAD of the repository and then run my start-up command.

So when I do git push  it works fine.

Thing is, when i SSH into the box, I use byobu. Is there a way to get the post-receive hook to run my start-up command inside a byobu session, so that when I SSH in, I can see my app running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byobu is just a wrapper around `screen` or `tmux`, so you want to send your command to one of those.

If you use `tmux`, you can just use the following command to litarally type in a command, then press enter, in the window number 2:

```
tmux send-keys -t 1 "start-app.sh" C-m
```

To set up `byobu` to use `tmux`, use either the command `byobu-select-backend` or start it with `byobu-tmux`.